# HTTPS- Certificate

Tags: https

[image]

I have created keys using below command

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048

After the i have exposed HTTPS connetion using camel end points

public class HTTPSCamelEndPoint {

```
public Endpoint httpsConfig(CamelContext context) throws Exception
{
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("C:\\Users\\sithamparamd\\keystore.jks");
    ksp.setPassword("123456");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("password");

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent =context.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);

    jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

    //jettyComponent.createEndpoint("jetty:https://192.168.16.98:4443/myservice");


    return jettyComponent.createEndpoint("jetty:https://192.168.16.98:4443/myservice");
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HTTPSCamelEndPoint httpsCamelEndPoint= new HTTPSCamelEndPoint();
    CamelContext camelContext=httpsCamelEndPoint.getContext();
    final Endpoint endpoint=httpsCamelEndPoint.httpsConfig(camelContext);
    System.out.println(endpoint);
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            from(endpoint).process(new Processor() {

                public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("GOT THE MSG !!!!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    camelContext.start();


}

public CamelContext getContext()
{
    CamelContext camelContext=new DefaultCamelContext();
    JettyHttpComponent httpComponent=new JettyHttpComponent();
    camelContext.addComponent("jetty", httpComponent);
    return camelContext;
}
```

}

but when i access through the URL its showing as invalided certificate. Please tel me the reason for this and give the solution for over come this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning, since you are using self-signed certificate that you generated is not trusted by the browser.

The warning will not occur when you use CA Certificate [What are CA Certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778623%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

You can suppress the warning by adding the certificate to the trusted root CA store [Example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A self-signed certificate would not be recognised by the browser. Only CA signed certificate could be recognised.

You can set up a free trusted certificate with the Let's Encrypt project, this is the [how-to tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

And this is a wiki of [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

Comment: Your answer is "almost correct". It works if one has Apache in front of the Java web server. Here is a link to Java specific instructions to use Let's Encrypt issued certificates: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/enabling-https-in-your-java-server-using-a-free-certificate

Comment: yes, I just assume that you use apache like me, thanks your blog link about the ca of java server